# How can I fetch a specific array from the JSON data and display it?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

Firstly apologies as I am fairly new to fetching from an API and I am trying to learn.

I need to fetch "name" , "age" and "phone" from "id" 1 from "is" and display it when click on button. This is my javascript-fetch-api.js file:

I'm not sure how to fetch only from id 1 "is"

```js
const events = [{
  "id": 1,
  "language": {
    "is": {
      "name": "Ali Sakaroğlu",
      "age": 27,
      "phone": "05368218685",
      "tags": [
        "Gallery",
        "STAK",
        "Gallery Julius",
        "mom",
        "young",
        "lorem",
        "ipsum",
        "show",
        "born",
        "worm",
        "dorm",
        "norm",
        "dlla"
      ]
    },
    "en": {
      "name": "Ali Sakaroğlus",
      "age": 27,
      "phone": "05368218685",
      "tags": [
        "Gallery",
        "STAK",
        "Gallery Julius",
        "mom",
        "young",
        "lorem",
        "ipsum",
        "show",
        "born",
        "worm",
        "dorm",
        "norm",
        "dlla"
      ]
    }
  }
}]


let output = '<ul>';
events.forEach((event) => {
  output += `<li>${event.id})  Name: ${event.name} - Age: ${event.age} - Phone: ${event.phone} </li> `;
});

output += '</ul> <hr>';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve] since the fetch obviously workd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside event you have id and language, not name, age and phone.
if you want to get name, age and phone from "is", you should type:

```
 event.language.is.age
 event.language.is.name
 event.language.is.phone
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I tried changing it, but now Im getting this error message in console; Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.
promiseEmptyOnRejected
promiseReactionJob

Comment: I checked and it works. you can see it here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-341tym?file=script.js

Comment: from what I can see, this solution fixes the problem with your supplied code and answers your question. If you have another issue with your code that goes beyond the scope of this question, then you should post a separate question. Please try and avoid changing the asked question in the same post, as it makes it harder for us to answer and harder for readers  to gain value.

Comment: If you click [edit] and then `[<>]` you can post the actual solution here instead of on a page that may disappear

Comment: @mplungjan the question was "how to get name, age, and phone from 'is'" and what I posted was Answer on this question. The author had different error and has nothing to do with that question.

Comment: You can STILL post the answer code here for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can drill down on the object like this to get `name` etc from the `is` property:

```
      output += `<li>${event.id})  Name: ${event.is.name} - Age: ${event.is.age} - Phone: ${event.is.phone} </li> `;
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide me with your live feed.
I will help you provide the best solution for your query but for now, I am adding a solution similar to your issue

```
live code: https://jsfiddle.net/cu2q9dzm/
```

```js
function getJson() {
  fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FEND16/movie-json-data/master/json/movies-in-theaters.json').then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data.forEach(data => {
      console.log("id: ", data.id, "year: ", data.year, "title: ", data.title);
    }));
}
getJson();
```

Comment: If you click [edit] and then `[<>]` you can post code here